# Does flutter SDK provide any framework to develop apps for Windows phone?

Tags: dart, windows-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to know whether google is planning to support any other platforms other than iOS and Android for Cross platform development using Flutter.

Like React native windows for React native does flutter have framework that would support windows phone development?

Comment: Windows Phone has less than 1% market-share. I’m curious why you want to target it.

Comment: @Dai yes. But still I am asking this out of curiosity. Because react native gives windows support. Can we see this in Flutter too?

Comment: no, there is no support for WIndows.  I would point out that while Windows 10 Phone has a small market share the same app will run on the other 600M devices that run Windows 10, so being able to build an app that could also run on Windows 10 would be interesting to many people.

Comment: @JohnWiese thanks for answering. I would be good if it happens. As Flutter is still in alpha, can we expect the windows support?

Comment: https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding is an attempt to make Flutter available to desktop OSes. Flutter is beta since ~2 weeks

Comment: I would not hold my breath on windows phone support.  Even Microsoft is backing away from it.

Comment: @dai  Flutter will run on iPad and Android tablets, how is that any different than a Surface?  If you support Surface, then you support running on any Windows 10 device, so Raspberry Pi (or smaller IoT) up to Surface Hub and everything in between.  That is the beauty of UWP.  Too many people still think of it as WIndows Phone vs. Windows. There are 600+M Windows 10 devices out there that can be targets with one build, would love to see Flutter expand at some point to output a UWP package.

Comment: @JohnWiese UWP is a joke: Applications are subject to an insanely restrictive sandbox and can only really be distributed through the user-unfriendly Windows App Store: there's a reason desktop front-end developers are choosing platforms like Electron over UWP. Also please consider the substantial paradigm differences between a phone and tablet vs a desktop/laptop: just because a phone app will run on the desktop doesn't mean it will be a good experience: the entire UI will need to be re-developed for a mouse+keyboard-first UI, at which point you're better-off rewriting the desktop UI entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can answer this question except Google, however it seems very unlikely that anyone would put effort into Windows Phone when even Microsoft are not:

> Of course we'll continue to support the platform.. bug fixes, security updates, etc. But building new features/hw aren't the focus.
>
> https://twitter.com/joebelfiore/status/917071399541391360

As for:

> support any other platforms other than iOS and Android for Cross platform development using Flutter

This is not officially supported, but lots of people in the community are interested in running Flutter on desktop and have been playing around with it. Maybe in future it'll cover more platforms even if they're not official or from Google.

https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding

Comment: My only comment is that you don't "put effort into Windows Phone" anymore, you put effort into "Universal Windows Platform" which will run on ANY Windows 10 device.

Comment: @JohnWiese Judging by your job-title of "Principal Technical Evangelist" I'm assuming you're at Microsoft. If so then you should disclose this in your posts because they come across as spam.

Answer (score 1):

A job we are doing right now has windows phone compatibility as a requirement.

My suggestion is to look into exporting Flutter to Web and then making a windows app which is just a full screen webview and loading the flutter web app in the app's internal webview.