# Development of old window phone Apps using flutter

Tags: flutter, windows-phone-8, windows-10-mobile

can I ask I still have a hope that my old window phone can be back to life again... can I develop Apps for window phones using Flutter.

Comment: I think reading this, will help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185603/does-flutter-sdk-provide-any-framework-to-develop-apps-for-windows-phone

Answer (score 0):

First make android app and get the apk then convert into windows phone app.
follow these instructions if you can, you can make it https://www.windowslatest.com/2017/06/02/install-android-apps-windows-10-mobile/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try that

Comment: ABSOLUTELY NO! Please, if you want to develop apps for Windows 10 Mobile, use native UWP. Developing and universal app is intuitive and final product is performant and nice looking. Definitely do not develop Android app and then convert it to work on Windows phones. iI only it were that easy, platform had not to die...

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge no !!! there is no support for Windows Phone.

And there is already answer in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49207065/11789675)

Nobody can answer this question except Google.